# How to exchange small amounts of dogecoin to bitcoin?

Tags: transaction-fees, dogecoin

I want to convert a small amount of dogecoin (about 200D) to BTC. However, I've noticed that the withdrawal fees on all exchanges are more the amount of bitcoin I will have.
Is there no way of exchanging small amounts with a fee I can pay?

Thanks,
part12

Answer (score 1):

One Doge/BTC exchange I know is https://shapeshift.io - but they are currently down since it was hacked last weekend. Even small amounts was working (I don't know the exact minimum since there down currently - but some hundred Doge was possible).

Maybe they will come back again in the next few days...

Comment: Oh well, shame they have been hacked. At least I know a website now. If anyone else knows another website could you please tell me? Thanks for your response user34875.

Answer (score 0):

No. The minimum withdrawal amounts are there because of the fees that the exchange needs to pay to send your transaction. Fees are rising, so the truth is that Bitcoin is no longer a good option for micropayments at a reasonable price.

My advice would be to simply store the BTC you get when exchanging your DOGE and withdraw only when you have enough. I would always advise against storing funds in an exchange, but in this case the amounts will be small and you don't have much of an alternative.